# Can't understand this apple documentation: Handling NotNow Status Responses on iOS

Tags: mdm, documentation

I'm looking at Apple's documentation for managing an organization's devices remotely. On [the page that addresses "NotNow" responses](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/implementing_device_management/handling_notnow_status_responses), it says

> Avoid receiving a NotNow status response on iOS devices by executing any of the following commands:

This looks pretty strange to me, and I wonder if I'm not interpreting it correctly. Does it mean that any of the listed commands can be sent without risk of a 'NotNow' response? (I don't think so because my server is sending 'CertificateList', which is one of the commands in question, and it's getting a 'NotNow' response. And that's what led me to this documentation in the first place.)

What is the page trying to say? And why does it address macOS in a manner so different from the way it addresses iOS? (For the former, it describes what conditions can cause a 'NotNow' response; for the latter, it just gives a list of commands which will supposedly prevent 'NotNow' responses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means that any of the listed commands can be sent without the risk of a `NotNow` response. Essentially, on iOS lots of commands cannot be processed when the device is locked after a boot - you'll get a `NotNow` response if you try. However, those commands in that list will not give you a `NotNow` response.

Your question about why Apple has chosen to describe macOS in a different way than iOS in the documentation is guess work and cannot be answered by anyone but the person writing the documentation. Essentially they describe the situations where a command could give a `NotNow` in macOS, and on iOS they list commands that cannot give a `NotNow`. It's just a choice in writing.